# c++ fstream - creating own formatting flags

Tags: c++, fstream, flags

i need to create new flags for the format of the output file. i have a class

```
class foo{
    bar* members;
    ofstream& operator<<(ofstream&);
    ifstream& operator>>(ifstream&);
};
```

and i want to use it like:

```
fstream os('filename.xml');
foo f;
os << xml << f;
os.close();
```

this will save an **xml** file.

```
fstream os('filename.json');
foo f;
os << json << f;
os.close();
```

and this an **json** file.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily create yor own manipulators, either hijacking an existing
flag or using `std::ios_base::xalloc` to obtain new stream specific
memory, e.g. (in the implementation file of `Foo`:

```
static int const manipFlagId = std::ios_base::xalloc();

enum
{
    fmt_xml,        //  Becomes the default.
    fmt_json
};

std::ostream&
xml( std::ostream& stream )
{
    stream.iword( manipFlagId ) = fmt_xml;
    return stream;
}

std::ostream&
json( std::ostream& stream )
{
    stream.iword( manipFlagId ) = fmt_json;
    return stream;
}

std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Foo const& obj )
{
    switch ( dest.iword( manipFlagId ) ) {
    case fmt_xml:
        // ...
        break;
    case fmt_json:
        //  ...
        break;
    default:
        assert(0);  //  Or log error, or abort, or...
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Declare `xml` and `json` in your header, and the job is done.

(Having said this, I rather think that this is a bit of an abuse of
manipulators.  Formats like xml go beyond simple, local formatting, and
are best handled by a separate class, which owns the `ostream`, and
writes the entire stream, and not just individual objects.)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is the biggest flaw in the iostream library.

James Kanze's solution is a partial one that will work in your own classes but in general objects are given a distinct way of streaming.

My usual means is to create my own wrapper class with a function that you can pass into your stream, and with xml would contain overloads to `xml_node()` or `xml_attribute()` e.g.

```
os << xml_attribute( "Id", id );
```

will set the attribute Id to whatever is in the variable in xml format.

I have also written node scopes too so they will write to stream the node-opening text on construction and automatically write the closing logic on destruction.

The advantage of my method over James Kanze's solution is that it is extensible. I think James Kanze's closing comment suggests he doesn't endorse his solution and would probably use something more like mine.

With the solution above, in order to add more formats you have to edit the operator<< functions all over the place, whilst json formatting code would be a completely different set of functions and if you added yet another format you would add the code for it without having to edit any existing code.

For inputting, by the way, for XML you would use an existing DOM or SAX parser and wouldn't be using iostream directly in this way.

Comment: I don't think using a stream directly to output XML is an appropriate solution.  A stream is an abstraction of a stream, not a hierarchial data structure.  For outputting XML, I'd use a library like Xerces; something which allows insertion in a hierarchial structure.  For the rest: wrapper classes are useful if you need unusual formatting for a built-in type, or for very complicated structures, but manipulators work well in a large number of cases.

Comment: To be more precise (and perhaps that is what you mean as well): outputting to a globally different format should be done with a different mechanism than stream: custom manipulators are for single custom types, not something which affects the output of all types.  (And you can't add formatting options to `int`).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that comes to mind is to start by creating a tag type and a single instance thereof:

```
struct JsonStreamTag {} json;
```

Then let such a tag construct an object to wrap the stream:

```
class JsonStream {
public:

    // (1)
    friend JsonStream operator<<(std::ostream& ostream, const JsonStreamTag&) {
        return JsonStream(ostream);
    }

    // (2)
    template<class T>
    friend JsonStream& operator<<(JsonStream& json_stream, const T& value) {
        write_json(json_stream.ostream, value); // (3)
        return json_stream;
    }

protected:

    JsonStream(std::ostream& ostream) : ostream(ostream) {}

private:

    std::ostream& ostream;

};
```

The constructor is `protected` to ensure that you can only use `some_ostream << json` (1) to construct a `JsonStream`. The other insertion operator (2) does the actual formatting. You then define an overload of `write_json()` (3) for every relevant type:

```
void write_json(std::ostream& stream, int value) {
    stream << value;
}

void write_json(std::ostream& stream, std::string value) {
    stream << '"' << escape_json(value) << '"';
}

// Overloads for double, std::vector, std::map, &c.
```

Alternatively, omit (2) and add overloads for `operator<<(JsonStream&, T)` instead.

Then just follow the same process to write the corresponding `XmlStream` using `XmlStreamTag` and `write_xml()`. This presumes that your output can be constructed completely from the particular values you’re writing; if you need some header or footer that’s the same across every file you’ll write, just use the constructor and destructor:

```
XmlStream(std::ostream& ostream) : ostream(ostream) {
    ostream << "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><my_document>"
}

~XmlStream() {
    ostream << "</my_document>";
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a very good idea.  It doesn't work for things like `out << json << "Header: " << obj;` for example.  (Of course, for something like XML, this would make no sense anyway.  But that's an argument for not using manipulators in the first place.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: The question isn’t clearly defined. For the purposes of answering the question literally, I made the assumption that a “JSON stream” would treat everything as a JSON value. But I do think such a thing is misguided in the first place.

Comment: XML (and JSON, as far as I know) are not streams; they are more complex structures.  An unrelated type should not output XML or JSON to an `ostream`; it should insert it into some instance of an XML or a JSON data structure, which would then take care of the streamed output, at a file level.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree. Streams are for flat data, and JSON and XML are both inherently nested. You could use RAII to enable scope-based nesting—`{ std::cout << json::object << ...; }`—but I see no advantage to that over just using the right data structure.