# Can i overload the << operator for a class type to produce a text and a binary file in C++ while being able to chain the << operation?

Tags: c++, overloading

I want to overload the `<<` operator in C++ to produce a binary and a text file for the following class type.

```
class data
{
   public :
   int a;
   char b;
}
```

how can i overload the `<<`  operator to produce both a binary and a text file for this class type like so:

```
ostream& operator(ostream &out, data &d) //for text
{
   out<<d.a<<' '<<d.b<<'\n';
   return out;
}

and
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, data &d) //for binary
{
  // code to serialize class data to store it in binary
   return out;
}
```

the problem is i cannot pass two different ostreams (like so `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out1, ostream& out2, data& d)` ) to `<<` at the same time because of the prototype or the way the `<<` operator is defined, in which it only takes one `ostream` as `parameter`.
Also since i can only pass one ostream to the `<<` operator i won't be able to chain the `<<` operation for the class for both the text and binary file at the same time.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "a binary and a text file"?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps use your own stream manipulator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629949/c-fstream-creating-own-formatting-flags

Comment: one text file where the user can view the data in word programs as well as one binary file that the program i am writing can open only. i have reasons to do so.

Comment: @IronMan i will take a look at it. thanks!

Comment: @IronMan that stuff seems complicated. I do not have enough understanding of streams. Do you have any recommendation of where i can learn in depth about streams?

Comment: You can write an `OutputHandler` of your own that maintains two fstreams with different modes, one for each output file, and give it a stream insertion operator (`<<`). Would that suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than define an `operator<<` for `data`, create 2 wrappers to represent the 2 formats you want, and then define `operator<<` for them instead.

```
class data
{
public:
    int a;
    char b;
};

struct asText
{
    const data &m_data;
    asText(const data &d) : m_data(d) {}
};

struct asBinary
{
    const data &m_data;
    asBinary(const data &d) : m_data(d) {}
};

ostream& operator(ostream &out, const asText &d)
{
    out << d.m_data.a << ' ' << d.m_data.b << '\n';
    return out;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const asBinary &d)
{
    // code to serialize d.m_data to store it in binary
    return out;
}
```

Then you can decide which format you want to use when calling `operator<<` on a per-call basis, eg:

```
data d;
...
stream1 << asText(d)
...
stream2 << asBinary(d)
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you!